# Using OVER() if customer has watch gladiator then 1 else 0 SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I think I need some guidance as to what is wrong in my query. I am trying to do

```
Watched_Gladiator=CASE WHEN FilmName IN (CASE WHEN FilmName LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN 1 END) then  OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_Nr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Tried this one too:

```
Watched_Gladiator=CASE WHEN FilmName IN (CASE WHEN FilmName LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN Filmnamne END) then  OVER(PARTITION BY Cust_Nr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

The Error I am currently getting is this:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.
```

This is basically how my data looks like

```
Cust_Nr    Date        FilmName                     Watched Gladiator      
    157649306   20150430    Gladiator                        1
    158470722   20150504    Nick Cave: 20,000 Days On Earth  0
    158467945   20150504    Out Of The Furnace               0
    158470531   20150504    FilmA                            0
    157649306   20150510    Gladiator                        1
    158470722   20150515    Gladiator                        1
```

I want to create a column (1 or zero) that shows if the customer has watched Gladiator then 1 ELSE 0. How can I do that?

I created a test column trying with a simple LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN 1 ELSE 0. The problem with this solution is that it will show 1(one) more than once if the customer has watched multiple times. I  only need 1 or zero.

I feel I am really close to finding a solution. I am very new to using OVER() and CASE WHEN but enjoying the thrill:=)

Comment: This seems not to be the customer table but one that stores what the customer has watched. You have to use the customer table, then you don't need to group by the Cust_Nr.

Comment: `OVER()` is a `WINDOW` function, used with Aggregate/Ranking functions. I think you don't need the `OVER()` at all

Comment: Group by cust_nbr and filmname, then do case when filmname = 'Gladiator' then 1 else 0 end.

Comment: It is funny how values in a table can make people assume things.:=) Had it been read properly then no problem.

Comment: @dotnetN00b look at the other questions he's raised and take your pick. Most of them are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to group by customer and add a column if this customer watched a specific film?

You could do:

```
SELECT Cust_Nr, MAX(Watched_Gladiator) 
FROM( SELECT Cust_Nr, 
            Watched_Gladiator = CASE WHEN EXISTS
            (
              SELECT 1 FROM CustomerFilm c2
              WHERE c2.Cust_Nr = c1.Cust_Nr 
              AND   c2.FilmName LIKE '%Gladiator%'
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
     FROM CustomerFilm c1 ) X
GROUP BY Cust_Nr
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb344/1/0)</kbd>

But it would be easier if you used the customer-table instead of this table, then you don't need the group-by.

Comment: Hello, I saw the keyword "MAX" and figured it out :=) Watched_Gladiator=MAX(CASE WHEN Filmnamne LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END.

Comment: @dataaddicted - I would love to see the final query you wrote. If you could added it to your OP, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

So you're saying that:

```
SELECT Cust_Nr, Date, FilmName, 
       CASE WHEN FilmName LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WatchedGladiator
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn = @somevalue
```

Doesn't work? Because according to the data you've given, it should.

EDIT:

Well based on Tim's comment, I would simply add this bit to the query.

```
   SELECT Cust_Nr, Date, FilmName, WatchedGladiator
   FROM
   (
      SELECT Cust_Nr, Date, FilmName, 
             CASE WHEN FilmName LIKE '%Gladiator%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WatchedGladiator
      FROM YourTable
      WHERE YourColumn = @somevalue
   ) as wg
   WHERE WatchedGladiator = 1
```

Comment: No, he wants to know for every customer if he watched a film that contains "Gladiator" but not necessarily in this record (imo).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I think the edit should satisfy the OP's basic requirements. But to answer the OP's other question. OVER() isn't needed for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following does what you want for all films:

```
select r.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by filmname order by date) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsWatchedFirstAndGladiator
from results r;
```

For just Gladiator:

```
select r.*,
       (case when filmname = 'Gladiator' and row_number() over (partition by filmname order by date) = 1
             then 1 else 0
        end) as IsWatchedFirst
from results r;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping up to the cust/film level:

```
select
cust_nbr,
case when film_name like '%Gladiator%' then 1 else 0 end
from
(
select
    cust_nbr,
    film_name
    from
    <your table>
    group by
    cust_nbr,
    film_name
) t
```

Or, as an alternative:

```
select distinct cust_nbr
from
<your table>
where 
filmname = 'Gladiator'
```